# Instance variable usage search IDEA 11 vs IDEA 12

Tags: java, intellij-idea, full-text-search

I recently upgraded from IDEA 11.1.5 to 12.1.6.

In v11, when I did a "Find Usages" on a field, it would search for usages of that field directly, in JPQL queries, and via getters/setters (left). In v12, it no longer searches getter/setter usages (right).

[image: usage search in v11]
[image: usage search in v12]

In order to get the same search results in v12, I have to do 3 usage searches (one on the field, one on the getter, and one on the setter). I've poked around the settings and key bindings but have yet to find a way to do the same comprehensive search. **Is there still a way to do this in IDEA 12?** I have to be missing something obvious...

**Update:** I upgraded to v13.0, but this is still a problem. I've filed an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117603) with JetBrains.

**Update 2:** This is only a problem with JPA entities. When searching a POJO, you'll get a prompt asking if you want to also search accessors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I wasn't missing anything. This was a bug and has been fixed in 13.0.2.